# NPM remains the same version after successful upgrade - Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, npm

I'm trying to upgrade NPM from v3 to v5 on Ubuntu Linux, but it remains the same version, what am I doing wrong?

`npm -v` >> `3.10.6`

`npm i -g npm` >> `npm@5.2.0`

`npm -v` >> `3.10.6`

Comment: Did you install the Ubuntu package `npm`? What is the output of `whereis npm`?

Comment: Then try deleting the package from the hidden `.npm` folder in your home directory.

Comment: `npm: /usr/bin/npm /usr/bin/X11/npm /usr/local/bin/npm`
Deleting the `.npm` folder didn't help.

Comment: You need to uninstall Ubuntu's `npm` package if you decide to use `npm` to upgrade itself. A more flexible solution is using `nvm` (more than 20,000 stars on GitHub: https://github.com/creationix/nvm). `nvm` lets you switch between `node`+`npm` versions on the fly.

Comment: How do I uninstall the npm package? I tried `sudo apt-get remove npm` but it says it's not installed

Comment: Did you try `npm update -g npm`?

Comment: Yes of course. It seems like I need to uninstall Ubuntu's nodejs package as it comes with npm 3.